# Why give "parameter count mismatch" error?

Tags: sqlite, qt

Give this error when try to save data into sqlite database.

I have search in google but do not find any solution.

```
//collect data
    QString u_name = ui->txt_name->text();
    QString contact = ui->txt_mobile->text();
    //int mobi = contact::number();


    QString save_stmnt = "insert into phonebook(name, mobile) values (:u_name, :contact)";

    cdb->getQuery()->prepare(save_stmnt);
    cdb->getQuery()->bindValue(":u_name",u_name);
    cdb->getQuery()->bindValue(":contact",contact);

    if(cdb->getQuery()->exec()){
        qDebug() << "data saved";
    } else {
        qDebug() << cdb->getQuery()->lastError().text();
    }
```

why give this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Does the phonebook table have other fields? if they have it then do those fields have default values? You could point out how you created that table.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT, but this looks suspicious to me.  Are you actually binding the parameter values to the prepared statement?  Or do you need to store/reference the prepared statement object in its own variable (from the call to `prepare()`)?

Comment: In other words, what type of object is the variable `cdb`?  (Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)